# image with tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to use tensorflow 2 (python 3.6) but just figured that my OS is problematic (see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56681399/install-tensorflow-2-problematic)). So I have a new question: is there a built environment, like a docker image, with tensorflow 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

yes!

You can use the tag for the version you need (perhaps `2.0.0b1`?)

SO, for example, running the command:

```sh
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0b1-py3-jupyter
```

will run the jupyter notebook version.

You can check out all the available tags on dockerhub: [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Tensorflow Enterprise by google. It gives a Jupyterlab which has more functionality compared to the Jupyter notebook. Here is a link you can use for instruction:
https://cloud.google.com/tensorflow-enterprise/docs/use-with-deep-learning-containers

I just have to note that the docker run command in the documentation is a little old. You can use this one instead (If you are using Nvidia because --runtime=nvidia is deprecated):

```
run --gpus all -d -p 8080:8080 --name=Name -v /path/to/local/dir:/home  gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf2-gpu.2-2
```